# How to properly pass function variables, objects, numbers, etc attached to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have "myupload" HTML file element that I want to click on dynamically and pass function variable to it like this:

```
myupload.dataset.function = function_variable;
myupload.click();
```

But here I have a problem that in a dataset that function is stored as the string datatype so I can't use it that way.

How to properly pass function variables, objects, numbers, etc attached to an HTML element?

More code:

```
const myupload = document.querySelector("#myupload");
if (myupload){
  myupload.addEventListener("change", event => {
    const e = event.target;
    if (typeof e.dataset.function === 'function'){
      //I need something like this
      e.dataset.function();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `myupload.onclick = function_callback;`?

Comment: No, I want to pass another function that will be called upon successful upload of a file

Comment: That's because html is nothing, but a string itself, as far as I understand. Can you please share more context (preferably js code)?

Comment: _"No, I want to pass another function that will be called upon successful upload of a file"_ — Your question as-written doesn't ask this at all. You should edit your question to rephrase and include this. You are actually asking about something that you _think_ is a way to accomplish this - see the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @StephenP well I thought my question is clear: I want to attach a function variable to an HTML element and use it later to call that function. Please check more code that I've added.

Comment: A dataset can only hold strings. You'll need to store your function object elsewhere - possibly having it indexed by a name stored in the dataset, or just attach it directly onto the element (although that's generally considered a bad practice - rather make the click handler a closure)

Comment: @Bergi, now we are on the right track, so by adding the function name I can check later if that function actually exists and if so execute it, maybe like this: if (typeof window[fname] === 'function') window[fname];

Comment: Put it in an object of your own rather than `window`. `myFunctions[fname] = function_variable`

Answer (score 1):

```
const someFunction1 = function() {
  //do stuff
};

const someFunction2 = function() {
  //do stuff
};

//build map of string to function
let functionMap = {};
functionMap['someFunction1'] = someFunction1;
functionMap['someFunction2'] = someFunction2;

myupload.dataset.function = 'someFunction2';

const myupload = document.querySelector("#myupload");
if (myupload) {
  myupload.addEventListener("change", event => {
    const e = event.target;
    if (Object.keys(functionMap).includes(e.dataset.function)) {
      functionMap[e.dataset.function]();
    }
  });
}
```